# Hidden locations with the only one way to reach them

Tags: deus-ex-mankind-divided

In Deus Ex HR I remember for sure there was a place in sewers where you can break the wall and find a praxis kit and this was the only way to get there. I wonder, are there similar locations in Mankind Divided where you can get inside only having specific aug (e.g. break the wall, jump high with no chance to help yourself with occasional crate, lift heavy object that is otherwise unmovable or run through long tunnel with gas/electric shocks)?

Comment: There definitely are a few of those. I've encountered a few aeration shafts that require high jump. You *can* bypass those using crates (no augment required), but this is extremely difficult, time consuming, and not at all intended by the devs.

Comment: Was it worth to get there? Did you get at least expirience bonus?

Comment: I don't remember much, except there were a couple of grenades and guns. It took me almost an hour to throw and push 2 small crates through the tight ventilation shaft. I think I found a praxis kit or a breach, not sure which, but it wasn't really worth spending an hour on.